# Awk inplace option with print statement

Tags: awk, replace

In recent version of awk there is a `inplace` option that can be used to do in place operations similar to `sed`'s -i option. However I can't make it work with `print` statement. Let's see my example.
The content of the file test is:

```
11 aa
22 bb
```

```
root@localhost:~# cat test
11 aa
22 bb
```

If I don't use `-i inplace`, I can get my desired result in the console.

```
root@localhost:~# awk 'BEGIN{print "begin"} $1=="11"{print "111" $2; next} 1; END{print "end"}' test
begin
111aa
22 bb
end
```

When I add `-i inplace`, this is what I got.

```
root@localhost:~# awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{print "begin"} $1=="11"{print "111" $2; next} 1; END{print "end"}' test
begin
end
root@localhost:~# cat test
111aa
22 bb
root@localhost:~#
```

How to improve my code and get what I want?

#### Update

---

My awk version is `4.1.1`.

```
root@localhost:~# awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p3, GNU MP 6.0.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
root@localhost:~#
```

#### Update2

---

```
root@localhost:~# awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.2, API: 1.1
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
root@localhost:~# cat file
11 aa
22 bb
root@localhost:~# awk 'BEGIN{print "begin"} $1=="11"{print "111" $2; next} 1; END{print "end"}' file
begin
111aa
22 bb
end
root@localhost:~# awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{print "begin"} $1=="11"{print "111" $2; next} 1; END{print "end"}' file
begin
end
root@localhost:~# cat file
111aa
22 bb
root@localhost:~#
```

Comment: Yes, the version is 4.1.1

Comment: I can reproduce your described effect with GNU awk 4.1.1, with BEGIN / END as well as with BEGINFILE / ENDFILE. Andrew Schorr informed in Usenet that there's a fix of that with GNU awk version 4.1.2.

Comment: @Janis: It seems that `BEGINFILE` worked but `ENDFILE` didn't. Can you please give us that link.

Comment: @Janis, I've tested on gawk 4.1.2 and it still not work. See my updates.

Comment: @OgrishMan: You should try `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`.

Comment: @Ogrish Man; From the semantics of GNU `awk`'s `inplace` - how should a `print` work if you process **more than one** file! - `BEGIN`/`END` can't work. I understood Andrew Schorr's hint as working with `BEGINFILE`/`ENDFILE`; try that.

Comment: @cuonglm; For reference to the mentioned Usenet posting search `comp.lang.awk` and the thread posted 2015-05-11.

Comment: @OgrishMan: It only worked with `BEGINFILE`, `ENDFILE` didn't. It can be a bug.

Comment: @cuonglm; The bug and effect you describe was (as far as I see) in `gawk` 4.1.1, and I just verified that it works in `gawk` 4.1.2 (with `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`). Make sure the proper `gawk` version is addressed in your installation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use BEGINFILE instead of BEGIN and ENDFILE instead of END for the begin and end to print into the file.

At least that works on cygwin.

```
Rob@Rob-PC /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 6.0.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation.


Rob@Rob-PC /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ echo "11 aa
22 bb" > test

Rob@Rob-PC /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "begin"} $1=="11"{print "111" $2; next} 1; ENDFILE{print "end" >> "test"}' test

Rob@Rob-PC /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ cat test
begin
111aa
22 bb
end
```

Comment: I've tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Yeah the begin works but not the end :(

Comment: You missed the last `end`.

Comment: Did you try my update :) with the >> in the ENDFILE to append to the file :)

Answer (score 0):

The `BEGIN` and `END` loops are run before the file is processed and after it has been processed in full. The `-i inplace` only makes sense while a file is being processed. I can't be sure without checking the source code but it therefore seems reasonable that the `BEGIN` and `END` won't work here.

As has already been suggested, that's what `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` are for. If those don't work in your setup, you will have to use workarounds. While matching the first line is easy (`if(NR==1){print "begin"}`), matching the last line is a bit more tricky. Some tricks you can use are:

1. Add the begin and end lines using another tool:

   ```
   perl -i -007ne 'print "begin\n${_}end\n"' file &&
       awk -i inplace '$1=="11"{print "111" $2; next}1;' file
   ```

   or

   ```
   printf "begin\n%s\nend" "$(cat file)"
   ```
2. Use `awk` for the "begin" and add the "end" later:

   ```
   awk -i inplace  'NR==1{print "begin"}$1=="11"{print "111" $2; next}1;' file && 
       echo "end" >> file
   ```
3. Do the whole thing using a tool that can understand `eof`. Perl's `-a` switch makes it act like `awk`: it will split fields on whitespace into the `@F` array. The Just like `awk`, the `-F` switch lets you set the field delimiter. The `-i` switch edits the file in place:

   ```
   perl -i -lane '$.==1 && print "begin"; eof && print "end"; 
                  if($F[0]=="11"){print "111$F[0] $F[1]"; next} print;' file
   ```